# How to view only 3 items on Owl Slider instead of 5

Tags: javascript, slider, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to implement owl slider in my website and it is working good but the only problem is that owl slider show 5 items on one slide by default so I need to make it 3 items to be display per slide instead of 5.

I have also tried to add below code which is available on it official website but it is not working for me please let me know how to fix.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.owl-demo').owlCarousel({
margin: 0,
responsiveClass: true,
smartSpeed: 500,
dots: ($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true: false,
loop:($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true: false,
responsive: {
    0: {
        items: 1,
    },
    1140: {
        items: 3,
    },
    1110: {
        items: 3,
    }
  } 
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and my problem is below:

1. I import a dynamic css style file;
2. When document is ready, the dynamic file have not loaded, but owl is inited;
3. And then the dynamic file loaded, now the dynamic file's some style resize owl-carousel container, but now owl's responsive is not triggered;

You may should init Owl when all style is ready.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    jQuery('.owl-demo').owlCarousel({
        margin: 0,
        responsiveClass: true,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        dots: ($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true : false,
        loop: ($(".owl-carousel .item").length > 1) ? true : false,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
            },
            1140: {
                items: 3,
            },
            1110: {
                items: 3,
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

---

Another workaround is below:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
}, 500);
```